# what is raylib required libraries in arch linux instead of mesa and

Tags: c++, installation, error-handling, arch, raylib

How to install raylib required libraries in the arch. All required libraries are for Debian. what are raylib required libraries for arch?

I installed raylib and created a CMakeLists.txt file for creating an executable file after running cmake and making the executable file created, but when I ran it, I got this error

```
INFO: Initializing raylib 4.0
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65544 Description: Wayland: Failed to connect to display
WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize GLFW
FATAL: Failed to initialize Graphic Device
```

**CMakeLists.txt codes**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(gamedev)

find_package(raylib REQUIRED)

add_executable(gamefight main.cpp)

target_include_directories(gamefight PRIVATE ${raylib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(gamefight PRIVATE ${raylib_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: This is more of a linux question. Since i'm on arch i can tell you that raylib and mesa exist. There is no official installation instructions on the raylib github page so either you need to figure out how to do it on arch, or i'd suggest switching to ubuntu which is one of the most widely supported development platforms and has instructions on their site.  https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-GNU-Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with remove `glfw-wayland` and installing `glfw-x11`

```
sudo pacman -S glfw-x11
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).